# Loading image into imageButton in cardview leaves white space in cardview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-glide

**Issue:**

I'm loading an image with glide and blur into a ImageButton inside a Relative layout inside a CardView. I've tried all the scale types but I can't make it work. The Relative layout is a must because I have other views inside that need to stack on the blurred image in some conditions. As you can see from the image below, there is a white space on the right side of the card view.

[image: cardview and image]

**Question:**

How to make the image fill the entire cardview while preserving the relative layout?

**XML:**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/photoPlaceRootView"
        android:layout_width="174.75dp"
        android:layout_height="246dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/photoPlace"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="127dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            
            card_view:fabCustomSize="27dp"
            card_view:fabSize="mini"
            card_view:maxImageSize="17dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_eye" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="127dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            card_view:backgroundTint="@color/main_pink_color"
            card_view:fabCustomSize="27dp"
            card_view:fabSize="mini"
            card_view:maxImageSize="17dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_heart" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Glide:**

```
Glide.with(activityContext).load(uri).transform(new BlurTransformation(100)).into(holder.photoPlace);
```

Please let me know if I should add anything else.

Comment: Can you try `ImageView` instead of `ImageButton`?

Comment: @Zain Just tried that and the same thing happened except now the images are cut off at the top as well. The space on the right remains persistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/photoPlaceRootView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/photoPlace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="246dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="0dp" />
```

Comment: Glide isn't loading the image correctly now, but at least the right side is filled now. Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, glide now load the image very slowly. I think this is happening because of combing the wrap_content with a specific height.

Comment: Fixed issue from the previous comment by using Picasso instead of Glide.